# How to center 2 buttons next to each other

Tags: css

I'm trying to center 2 buttons on the page next to each other side by side. I have set the display as inline-block and text-align as center but it remains left aligned. What am I doing wrong? https://jsfiddle.net/chLm4xj3/7/

```
.modal-content {
background-color: white;
margin: auto;
padding: 40px;
border: 1px solid red;
width: 80%;
border-radius: 15px;
box-shadow: 0em 0em .5em rgba(0 0 0 0.75);
text-align: center;
}

button {
border: 1px solid red;
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 16px;
display: inline-block;
margin: auto;
background-color: #4CAF50;
border-radius: 30px;
padding: 15px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: `modal-content` is not the container of the buttons

Comment: As your two buttons are next to each other, I would suggest to wrap them into a container.